# Installed ES Lint globally but getting error -bash: eslint: command not found

Tags: node.js, eslint, nvm

I am on a mac using Catalina.
I installed ES Lint globally using

```
npm install -g eslint
```

the output says

```
/usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin/eslint -> /usr/local/opt/nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
+ eslint@7.10.0
```

However I am confused because I made sure to use nvm uninstall node v10.13.0. Then I downloaded the latest install from the node website and installed it.
when I do node -v I get

```
v12.18.4
```

Why is it still installing ESlint it to the old  10.13.0 directory?

Comment: I'd suggest not installing ESLint globally. Just add it to each of your projects - it's easier to manage anyway. It also avoids problems like this one but also helps out if your projects use different versions of ESLint or similar. You can still invoke it from the locally installed package by using `npx eslint` instead of `eslint`. If you're not using it from the command line, most tools should already easily find the local package.

Comment: Hmm ok I will install it locally but do you know why I am getting the issue with node?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. I avoid global installations because I don't really want to deal with such issues.

Comment: I went to my project folder and did ```npm install -D eslint``` and it did + eslint@7.10.0 but if I try to do eslint -v in that folder I get -bash: eslint: command not found

Comment: `npx eslint -v`